# Puppet agent fail to connect to master

Tags: ssl, puppet

I'm struggling since 2 days with signing of Puppet-Agents now. The Problem is as follows:

On the master I delete all existing signatures with

> puppet cert clean esx-poc-1.xxx.de

On the agent I delete the whole ssl directory with

> rm -rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl/

After running one of the following commands on the agent...

> puppet certificate generate esx-poc-1.xxx.de --ca-location remote
>   puppet agent --server puppetmaster.int.xxx.com --waitforcert 60 --test

...I can list the certificates on the master with:

> puppet cert list --all

The output is:

> "esx-poc-1.xxx.de"         (SHA256)
>   71:72:D8:3E:09:9E:B1:5C:DA:78:A8:B8:A1:2B:E4:09:B8:00:8A:AF:49:02:CC:B2:B5:C3:25:79:59:0D:A8:F5
>   + "puppetmaster.int.xxx.com" (SHA256) 7B:00:8C:4F:CE:B2:0D:2F:A1:BB:A7:C4:25:B0:11:01:2B:EC:90:46:D1:CB:BE:AA:AD:3F:B4:70:0C:83:3F:78
>   (alt names: "DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppet.xxx.de",
>   "DNS:puppetmaster.int.xxx.com")

After signing the agent with:

> puppet cert sign esx-poc-1.xxx.de

The fingerprint differs from the one above:

> - "esx-poc-1.xxx.de"         (SHA256) 49:F6:59:FD:3C:28:C6:54:7F:6E:A7:56:56:DB:64:9A:E2:08:10:90:11:83:7A:A6:0E:E1:CD:39:F0:E0:1C:25

Is that correct?

Performing an agent-run aferwards results in the following error:

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue: Warning: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not retrieve facts for esx-poc-1.xxx.de: Failed to submit 'replace facts' command for esx-poc-1.xxx.de to PuppetDB at puppetmaster.int.xxx.com:8081: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate signature failure for /CN=puppetmaster.int.xxx.com] Info: Retrieving plugin Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/last_run.rb Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppi_projects.rb Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/iptables.rb Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to submit 'replace facts' command for esx-poc-1.xxx.de to PuppetDB at puppetmaster.int.xxx.com:8081: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate signature failure for /CN=puppetmaster.int.xxx.com] Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this exact same issue myself. The problem ended up being that the `puppetdb-terminus` package was at version `1.1.0` while `puppetdb` itself was still at `1.0.5`.

After downgrading `puppetdb-terminus` down to `1.0.5` everything operated normally.

Answer (score 1):

In puppet 3.4 I noticed that if the hostnames are not set this error could be thrown.

For example; I had two debian boxes; one was named `debian1` and the other `debian2` in the hosts file. But, both of their `/etc/hostname` settings where `debian`; after I changed their name with `hostname` and set their names in `/etc/hostname` they worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a dumb question, but, do you have a node definition for this machine?  I.e.,

```
node 'esx-poc-1.xxx.de' {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after changing permission of files in /etc/puppet. 
Changing them back to 'pe-puppet' (for an enterprise version) solved it for me

Answer (score -2):

After completely reinstalling puppetdb it's finally working...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.